# Symfony & Doctrine: Storing application configuration in the database?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm planning to store a few global configuration values (page title, page keywords, current theme, etc.) in the database. What's the best approach to this? Would you guys create a Doctrine Entity with two columns, option_key and option_value, or would you create a column for each configuration value?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a ConfigurationBundle with a controller to handle the config CRUD and then an entity with the 2 columns: option_name, option_value.

This way you can do calls like $optionsRepo->findOneByOptionName('some_option_name');
This will either give you the option or a null value. You can handle the result from there.

Comment: Any tips for improving the performance of such implementation?

Comment: There are plenty of guides out there for improving performance on symfony 2 applications. I wont really go into them here.

Answer (score 1):

As `Chausser` suggested, but I would go even further.

Either:

- implement `DoctrineFixtures` to ensure you **always** have a default data ([link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html))

**OR**

- Make sure you have the defaults stores in your `parameters.yml` (or some other for that matter)
- If option has not been found fallback to that default

Comment: I like this approach better. I am usually just too lazy to implement fallbacks but it is great practice